# How am I supposed to understand 充分一些？

Tags: meaning

What does the phrase 尽量准备充分一些 mean?

I have this sentence: 并非每个人都适合创业，但有想法的人可以大胆去做，尽量准备充分一些。

As much as possible prepare ample a little
尽量准备充分一些
Should I prepare a little, or a lot??

Comment: Functional-wise, "一些" here is something like "客套語" for politeness, making the sentence less aggressive/pushy.

Answer (score 2):

First: **充分**

I feel like the definition *ample* is slightly misleading, although it could be translated this way in specific contexts.

A Chinese-English Dictionary:

> 2 to the full; as fully as possible
>
> 充分利用
>
> fully utilize; make full use of

Oxford actually translates, what most translate as ample, as **abundant**.

---

Second: **一些**

Oxford

> 3 略微 [placed after an adjective, indicating a slight change in degree]
>
> 请走慢一些
>
> Please walk more slowly

So, we can think of an **一些** suffix as "a little more....blah blah blah", it is adding to whatever is already there.

**一些** = *and some*

---

Now we have **充分** + **一些** = a little more abundant (-or- a little more ample, if you really want to use ample) -or- with 准备 in mind: *to prepare a little more fully*

---

Now **尽量**

KEY:

> to the best of one's ability; as far as possible

---

尽量准备充分一些 = you should prepare a *whole* lot (**more**), as much as you possibly can

Comment: I think 一些 is there to make it more polite.  Does that seem right?

Comment: so would a summary interpretation be: "as much as you can (尽量), you should prepare (准备) fully (充分), more fully than you might otherwise (一些) "?

Comment: @ColinMcLarty Maybe you are thinking of 一下 which makes "commands" sound more like favors (让 vs. 让一下), 一些 doesn't really make anything sound more polite, at least I can't think of anything at the moment. *Here*, at least, 一些 function is basically "more 'X'-er"; 充分一些 could easily be understood as "more 充分er".

Comment: @MasterSparkles the "than you might otherwise" is more interpreted than actually written in the text. You can see the above comment I wrote to ColinMcLarty (i.e.: *一些 function is basically "more 'X'-er"*).

Comment: @user3306356: certainly - paraphrasing a lot here

Answer (score -1):

It means "prepare as much as you can". Thank you.